# How to emebed style instead of linking it with wp_enqueue_style in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

If you're using

```
wp_enqueue_style('handle-name', $loc);
```

you get something like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='handle-name' href='http://example.com/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Is there any easy way to get the content of the `style.css` inside a `<style>` tag?

```
<style>
   html,body {
   ...
   }
   ...
</style>
```

Is there a built in solution or have I do it manually. For performance I'll use a caching around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an include like this:

```
<style>
<? include('style.css'); ?>
</style>
```